# How to run a Javascript code via URL?

Tags: javascript

I would like to run a Javascript code via URL.

So let's say I have this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var nstParams = {pub: ' 9084232', pla: '9048223', ad_type: 'popup', numOfTimes: 3, duration: 24, period: 'hour'};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.clic2pub.com/js/file.1.js"></script>
```

In my website I don't have the option to place a Javascript code, I just can place a URL.

What I am looking for is that when the user clicks the URL, the Javascript code starts executing.

Comment: Are you using a website creator?

Comment: Is this your website? How much of it do you have access to (since you say you don't have the option to place JS code), what exactly can you change?

Comment: Yes, it is my website. I can upload files to the server easily. The thing is that the website is not coded to place a Javascript code where I need to place it. It just gives you the option to place a URL.

Comment: The odds are that you *do* have the option to include a script file, you just haven't found it yet. I would keep looking and/or get on the phone with support.

Comment: How can I call a script file via URL @T.J.Crowder?

Comment: @Alex: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it's **really** true that you can only specify URLs, not scripts, you're looking for [bookmarklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), which use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol: Basically: Put `javascript:` at the beginning of the href and follow it with URI-encoded JavaScript code.

**Live Example**:

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('hi%20there');">Click me</a>
```

It's **much** more likely, though, that you do have the option of including scripts somewhere you just haven't found. Which is good, because putting significant code in an `href` is awkward and difficult.

Comment: I just have the option to input a plain URL, not HTML code.

Comment: @Alex: `javascript:alert('hi%20there');` is a plain URL.

Comment: Ok, but how can I concatenate the two scripts of the example from my first post? I mean, the part with the "src" code.

Comment: @Alex: Search for how you add a script via code, since the above lets you add code. But again, seriously, no web host is going to put this restriction on you. Instead of trying to work within what you think is a restriction, get on the phone with them. Flat-out guarantee you're just misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<a href="javascript:var nstParams = {pub: ' 9084232', pla: '9048223', ad_type: 'popup', numOfTimes: 3, duration: 24, period: 'hour'};" >Run JavaScript Code</a>
```

Comment: I just have the option to input a plain URL, not HTML code.

Comment: @Alex, it looks like you are performing some sort of XSS exploit.

Comment: It is not for XSS exploiting. It is just for my personal use.

Comment: @Alex, then what you are trying to do is not possible. If you can't use html code you cant put in the js.

Comment: @Alex. if you are putting your url into a input box and submitting, you can try to break the submit function by using some basic injection techniques that would allow raw html to be inserted., but that requires more information.